# Use Regex to create custom validation rules

Tags: jquery, regex

I have an account rate input box in my html form and I need to use jquery validation plugin to validate the inputs. The properties of the account rate input box is that

1) when a negative value is entered, for e.g -1000, it should display an error message telling the user to enter a value greater than or equal to 0.

2) When alphabets or special characters are entered (e.g, &%#) are entered, it should display an error message telling the user to enter a number.

I have tried using the 'digits' and 'min' value of the jquery validation plugin, however, when -1000 is entered, the error message displayed is the same message displayed when alphabets/special characters are entered. However, i need the error message to be telling the user to enter a value greater than or equal to 0.

How do I go about this? I assume i'd need to use Regex? and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

Load these two cdns at top:

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js
```

after that in script tag enter the js code. Don't forget to change the name of your form in this code:

```
    $(function() {
        $("form[name='name-of-your-form']").validate({

             rules: {
              // The key name on the left side is the name attribute
              // of an input field. Validation rules are defined
              // on the right side
              accountrate:{
                required: true,
                minlength: 0,
                digits: true,
              }
            },
            // Specify validation error messages
            messages: {
                accountrate:{
                    required: "This field is required",
                    minlength: "Please enter a minimum length",
                    digits: "Please enter digits"
                }
            },
            // Make sure the form is submitted to the destination defined
            // in the "action" attribute of the form when valid
            submitHandler: function(form) {
              form.submit();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: This does not work as I have already mentioned in my original post. I get the exact same message displayed for both scenarios.